# Add arrays in an array into javascript file with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, multidimensional-array

I do not understand what is wrong ..

Basically I have a javascript file in which we find a multidimensional array. In my php file I decode the file.js with "json_decode", I check if the array that I have to add and the last array inside the "multidimensional arrays".
If they are different add.

The problem is that the addition does not go ..

This is file.js:

```
var eru = [
   [" 12 July-20 July 2015",18]
];
```

this file.php:

```
$intervallo= " 10 July-16 July 2015"
$numvulc= 25;
$aggiornamento= array($intervallo,$numvulc);

$fileeru= "out/eru.js";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileeru), true);

// how many arrays there are into multidimensional array **eru** 
$counteru= count($eru); 

//maybe here there's problem

if($eru[$counteru] != $aggiornamento){
  $eruzioni[]= $aggiornamento;
}

$eru= json_encode($eru);
$eru= 'var eru= '.$eru.';';
file_put_contents($fileeru,$eru);
```

comparing are different then I expect the file.js now is so:

```
var eruzioni = [
  [" 12 July-20 July 2015",18],
  [" 10 July-16 July 2015",25]
];
```

while is so:

```
var eruzioni = [
  [" 10 July-16 July 2015",25]
];
```

there is only **$aggiornamento** and last array was delete...
of course if in comparing the two arrays are equal not agiunge nothing and the file is not modified ..

thanks a lot !

Comment: Why are you doing that? For what purpose? What particular goal are you trying to gain?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with that code, but your biggest issue is that **JavaScript is not JSON** so you can't parse it with `json_decode`!

Comment: The file contains javascript **not** json. remove the `var eru=` and you probably have json. Also the php variable `$eru` is not initialized in the above code, and the variiable `$json` is not used

Comment: @Quentin I use **json_encode** to make the array written in PHP for file.js (I have recommended in another question), then I thought the opposite effect was **json_decode**. I'm wrong?

Comment: @Giovanni-Borgia — You don't **just** use `json_encode`. You add other stuff around it.

Comment: can you give me a suggestion?

Comment: why to use json you can create php file itself right

Comment: @raghavendra because than i will use file.js for anothere file.js with google maps

Comment: exist a function in php to convert javascript array in php array?

Comment: Just drop the `var eru=` part, then you have valid json (probably name the file as `name.json` as well for clarity). Then in your js load the json via ajax, instead of a simply script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the javascript file as json, you need to remove the var expression you put around it.  Since you seem unsure if you are using `var eru =` or `var eruzioni =` I have just used the first bracket.

Change this :

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileeru), true);
```

To this :

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents($fileeru);
$json_string = substr($file_contents,strpos($file_contents,'['),-1);
$json = json_decode($json_string);
```

**Edited to add:**
Consider the following code (I replaced the file functions, so you can paste it in phpcodepad.com and see how it works)

```
$intervallo= " 15 July-25 July 2015";
$numvulc= 30;
$aggiornamento= array($intervallo,$numvulc);

//$fileeru= "out/eru.js";
//$file_contents = file_get_contents($fileeru);
//GET DATA FROM STRING INSTEAD OF FILE
$file_contents = 'var eruzioni = [
  [" 12 July-20 July 2015",18],
  [" 10 July-16 July 2015",25]
];';
$json_string = substr($file_contents,strpos($file_contents,'['),-1);
$json = json_decode($json_string);

// how many arrays there are into multidimensional array **eru** 
$counteru= count($json);

//maybe here there's problem

if($json[$counteru-1] != $aggiornamento){
  $json[]= $aggiornamento;
}

$eru= json_encode($json);
$eru= 'var eru= '.$eru.';';
//file_put_contents($fileeru,$eru);
//ECHO INSTEAD OF WRITE TO FILE
echo '<pre>' . $eru . '</pre>';
```

Comment: i add   $counteru= count($json->result);
if($json[$counteru] != $aggiornamento){
 $json[]= $aggiornamento;
}
$eru= json_encode($json);
$eru= 'var eruzioni= '.$json.';';
file_put_contents($fileeru,$json);   but doesn'work... :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: sorry but why with your code i must delete only "[" and not both "[" and "]" ?

Comment: It should not delete the "[", that should stay in tact.

Comment: ahhh yes understand, and to know how many array there are in multidimensional array, is true to use **$counteru= count($json->result);** ?

Comment: No, you don't have any key named result, so it would just be `count($json[0])`

Comment: Sorry, I should not have put that [0] on there.  I was thinking it was nested one deeper.

Comment: hmm no only **count($json)** add **$intervallo** each time run file.php :/

Comment: ohh yeah now works! **$counteru= (count($json))-1;**